# Monitor doesn't work for a while after removing power cord

Tags: display, power-supply, power

If the light goes down or the cable cord is removed it can't power on again. I always have to unplug it for a whole night or day and plug it again, and then it works.

What I tried:
- Different power cables
- Different power outlets

It has 5 years now, and I'm moving soon so I don't want to buy a new one.
Which component seems to be wrong? I would like to fix it.

Comment: Take it to a repair shop [or just throw it away & buy a new one, because it will be cheaper]. This is one of those questions where if you have to ask, you don't have the skill-set to fix it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the monitor experiences a buildup of static charge, that you
need to wait for it to bleed away before it can turn on.

I suggest to check that the power-cord's third prong (earth) is functional.
You might try to connect a metallic wire between the monitor and some water pipe
or similar, as a check of this theory (not as a final solution).

If you can find no explanation, a repair-man is indicated.

Comment: I thought about the static charge too, but after 3 days with the monitor unplugged I can confirm is not the case.
I guess it's time to throw the monitor away.

Comment: The slowness of the recovery might indicate a capacitor problem, replaceable or not. I agree that investing might not be justified.